# DateTime.TryParseExact ignores DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a DateTime, when the format string does not provide the month and the year, but only the time and the day. So my assumption is that after the call below, the month and year will be set to 01 and 0001. However, the result shows that the month is set to 01 and the year is set to the current year 2021.

`DateTime.TryParseExact("5 11:20",  "d HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dateTime);`

This returns:
01/05/2021 11:20:00

It seems to work when I remove the day format:

`DateTime.TryParseExact("11:20",  "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dateTime);`

Code can be run here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YADrwn

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Seems exactly as expected - from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=net-5.0#fields) - "If the parsed string contains only the time and not the date..." but your parsed string *doesn't* just contain the time.

Answer (score 1):

In Reference Source, we can see that there is a computed flag `bTimeOnly` that is false if you have days, months or years.

The private function call by TryParseExact :
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,2558c4cbd566081b

The moment when it is checked if it's just a time or a date too:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,4134

The moment when it is assumed that only a day = current year, first month and read day :
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,ed47be441811082c

So, it's exactly the behaviour that you have. It seems to be intended.

Anyway, you can obtain the time part by using `dateTime.TimeOfDay`.